# Can you set ant flags in the build properties file?

Tags: ant, build

I want to run ant -emacs for only a certain target

can i add something like

```
   <property name="build.compiler.emacs" value="true" />
```

to do this?

Comment: I was asking because I set this in my build script and it didnt seem to work.

Comment: Could build.compiler.emacs already have been set (e.g. to false) before you reach the place where you set it to true? If so, the property is not reset subsequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a property like that anywhere in your build file. But once it is set, e.g. when containing target is invoked, it remains set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, either to your ant buildfile or to a build.properties file in [this Java properties format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29), according to the [these rules specified by ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html).